# Replacing a String statment that's being used by a constructor

Tags: java, string, constructor, switch-statement

So I'm working on a project to count the number of vowels and consonants of a desired string. I've got almost everything working, but I can't seem to get the option to replace the string with a new one to work properly. I think it's a problem with having the new choice be applied to the Driver construct but I can't seem to figure out a way to do that without breaking the program.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Driver{

 private String entry;

int vowels = 0;
int cons = 0;

 public Driver(String input){
  entry = input;
  this.count();
 }

 public boolean isVowel(char x){
  return (x == 'A' || x == 'E' || x == 'I' || x == 'O' || x == 'U' ||
   x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u');
 }

 public boolean isConsonant(char x){
  return (((x >= 'a' && x <= 'z') || (x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z')) && !isVowel(x));}

 public int getVowels(){
  return vowels;
 }

 public int getConsonants(){
  return cons;
 }

 public void count(){

  int l = entry.length();
  for(int i = 0; i < l; i++){
   if(this.isVowel(entry.charAt(i))){
    vowels++;
   }else{
    if(this.isConsonant(entry.charAt(i))){
     cons++;
    }
   }

  } 

 }
 static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

 public static void main(String[] args){

  int choice;   //Choice from menu
  int vowels = 0;  //# of vowels in entry
 int cons = 0;  //# of consonants in entry
  String entry;  //User's input

  System.out.print("Enter a string:");
  entry = kb.nextLine();
  do{
   Driver sentence = new Driver(entry);

   System.out.println("Enter a number");
   System.out.println("1. Count the number of vowels in the string");
   System.out.println("2. Count the number of consonants in the string");
   System.out.println("3. Count both the vowels and consonants in the string");
   System.out.println("4. Enter another string");
   System.out.println("5. Exit the program:");
   choice = kb.nextInt();

   switch(choice){

case 1:
 System.out.println("Vowels: " + sentence.getVowels());
 break;
case 2:
 System.out.println("Consonants: " + sentence.getConsonants());
 break;
case 3:; 
 System.out.println("Vowels: " + sentence.getVowels() + "\nConsonants: " + sentence.getConsonants());
 break;
case 4:
 System.out.print("Enter a string:");
 entry = kb.nextLine();
 //Driver sentence = new Driver(entry);
 break;
default:
 System.out.println("Please enter a value input: ");
   }

  }while(choice != 5);


 }

}
```

Comment: I believe I have one in there, a do while loop. what I'm having trouble with is in case 4, I want to replace the old string with a new one and I can't see to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the **Driver** Class on its own (without the **main()** method).

Then create another Class that will be your startup Class which will contain the **main()** method). For the sake of argument let's call it **VowelsAndConsonants**.

The problem that's causing all the grief is your keyboard entry of 1 to 5 for the Console menu. You are using the **Scanner.nextInt()** method which is okay as long as you know that the whatever is entered is not all consumed and remains within the Scanner buffer and this is because the **Scanner.nextInt()** method doesn’t read and consume the ***line separator*** that is applied when the Enter Key is hit. So, when **Scanner.nextLine()** is used as the next Scanner method the first thing it gets hold of is that ***line separator*** that's held within the Scanner buffer which in turn is just like hitting the Enter key and therefore it skips what was typed. On the other hand the **Scanner.nextLine()** method does read in and consume the ***line separator***. One way to get around this problem is to add (in your case) `kb.nextLine();` directly after the `choice = kb.nextInt();` code line. This forces the ***line separator*** to be consumed and empties the buffer. In essence the menu would then look something like this:

```
Driver sentence = new Driver(entry);
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a Menu choice (1 to 5): ");
    System.out.println("1. Count the number of vowels in the string");
    System.out.println("2. Count the number of consonants in the string");
    System.out.println("3. Count both the vowels and consonants in the string");
    System.out.println("4. Enter another string");
    System.out.println("5. Exit the program:");
    choice = kb.nextInt();
    kb.nextLine();  // Consume

    ..... the rest of your do/while code .....
}
```

> EDIT: Based on your Question in Comment: **"I'm curious as to why
>   there is a difference in how the line separator is dealt with tho. Is
>   this just something that is in Java, or is there a reason that it
>   isn't consumed from nextInt()?"**

The Scanner Class is quite involved. It is by design that the **nextInt()** does this since Scanner can work based on **tokens**. You can use **nextInt()** to accept multiple numbers on a single input using (for example) a whitespace delimiter and then with the **Scanner.hasNextInt()** or Scanner.hasNext() methods in conjuction with the Scanner.nextInt() you can individually acquire each value, for example:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(" *");
System.out.println("Enter numbers delimited with a white-space:  ");
while (kb.hasNextInt()) {
    int x = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

If you were to run this code and at the prompt enter on one line:

**2 4 6 8 10**

*(note the whitespace between numbers)* you will see a display within the Console window of:

**2

4

6

8

10**

Through each iteration of the **while** loop **x** would equal the next integer token from the line of numbers entered. This sort of thing however is best suited for reading numbers from a text file which Scanner can do as well. Read up on the **[Scanner Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)**.

Comment: This is great, it worked perfect, thanks! I'm curious as to why there is a difference in how the line separator is dealt with tho. Is this just something that is in Java, or is there a reason that it isn't consumed from nextInt()?

Comment: @Brandon - See **Edit** in answer above.

Comment: There is definitely a lot more I need to learn, thanks for the detailed explanation though!